# How to solve NoSuchDriver:A session is either terminated not started or Chromedriver exited unexpectedly with code null, signal SIGTRAP in appium?

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-desktop

Pre-req: Appium v1.16.0/chrome-driver 80

1. **Installed appium with chrome browser version 80**
2. **Started appium with --chromedriver-executable pointing to installed location of chromedriver in Mac OS.** (Note: If I don't mention executable path then I get no driver found to automate chrome 80.., hence I gave executable path for appium)
3. Source: Test-script in my windows machine
4. Destination: Appium server and android emulator available in Mac Desktop
5. **Requirement: Replay test-script from windows to mac**

   **Capabilities set in widows as below with appium server pointing to Mac OS**

   ```
       capabilities = {
               "automationName": "Appium",
               "platformName":"Android",
               "deviceName":"Pixel2",
               "browserName":"Chrome"
           };
   ```

   **Below are details of appium server running in Mac desktop OS**

   ```
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://10.3.73.7:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities )
   ```

**Output:** Fails to launch webpage with below error.

```
    NoSuchDriver: [POST http://10.3.73.78:4723/wd/hub/session/62c4c813-daa9-4b03-ae0c-9b6e6c222a83/url / {"url":"data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Ciframe%20id%3D%22inlineFrame%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E"}] 
A session is either terminated or not started
```

**Appium logs from MacOS can be accessed from below link**

https://anotepad.com/notes/rtpbaf7g

Note: Replay on iOS simulator from windows to same appium server works well.

Comment: Got to know that issues is with chrome-driver 80. Hence, used lower chrome-driver version which resolved issue. https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-solve-nosuchdriver-a-session-is-either-terminated-or-not-started-error-in-appium-when-test-is-replayed-from-windows-to-mac-os-desktop/29919

Comment: Issue 3339: Chromedriver exited unexpectedly with code null, signal SIGTRAP - if you encounter SIGTRAP issue, same solution applies as above.

Answer (score 0):

Got to know that issues is with chrome-driver 80. Hence, used lower chrome-driver version which resolved issue https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-solve-nosuchdriver-a-session-is-either-terminated-or-not-started-error-in-appium-when-test-is-replayed-from-windows-to-mac-os-desktop/29919